# How to inject mock for @Lookup annotation in spring

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

```
@Component
public class SomeFactory implements ISomeFactory {

    public someWatchFactory() {};
    @Override
    public boolean startWatch(MethodToWatch methodName, UUID uniqueID, Callable toRun) {
        IPerformanceStopWatch mywatch = getStartWatch(methodName,uniqueID,toRun);
        return mywatch.startWatchDeployTaskStatus();
    }

     @Lookup
    private IPerformanceStopWatch getStartWatch(MethodToWatch methodName, String uniqueID, Callable toRun) {
        IPerformanceStopWatch mywatch = getStartWatch(methodName,uniqueID,toRun);
        return null;  //stub implementation which will be replaced by the container
    }
}
```

I would like to test the factory class, using something like:

```
@InjectMock
ISomeFactory someFactory;

@Mock
IPerformanceStopWatch performanceWatch
```

That whenever the lookup annotation inside the `SomeFactory` class will try to get the instance, it will use the mock.

How should i do it?